# Remove the duplicates with particular condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Data frame :

[image]

here i want to remove duplicates and the output should when it hits india.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you first post the data in the images as text please, second if you briefly explain the logic that will be good

Comment: Thank you ! it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or maybe like @anky_91 said but with `subset`:

```
df[df.Region.str.contains('india',case=False,na=False)].drop_duplicates(subset='ticket')
```

Comment: nothing but a guess based on the pictures though :)